# Did Kleinfeld steal from a client?

Tags: plot-explanation, carlitos-way

In a scene in *Carlito's Way*, the lawyer Kleinfeld is confronted by a gangster client doing time on Riker's Island- it seems this mob boss entrusted Kleinfeld with a million dollars that were supposed to go to the boss's son, which the mob boss/client claims never happened, that his son "never saw a dime of my money... that a million bucks went straight into your pocket."

To me there seem to be three possible outcomes- Kleinfeld really did pocket the money, the boss (who appears to be in failing health) is being paranoid, or his son did get the million and is lying about it for some reason- which is the likeliest scenario?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you missed a later scene, perhaps it was cut for timing or something.

In the [transcript](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/c/carlitos-way-script-transcript.html) of the original theatrical release, when Carlito and Dave go out on Dave's boat into the Long Island Sound to get Taglialucci off of a buoy along with T's son Frankie. Dave then kills both Taglialucci and Frankie. Carlito then accuses Dave of actually stealing the money from Taglialucci and Dave admits doing so.

If you have trouble finding it in the transcript, search for "You did take the million dollars, didn't you"